# How can I run my program in the background at certain times of the day?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a program using python which moves goes through each file in my downloads directory, and moves that file to another directory based on the suffix at the end of the file (.mp3, .mp4, .txt, .jpg, ...). How would I go about automating this program so that it runs in the background of my computer every couple of hours?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Running a script at certain time soft the day should be handled by the OS; hence the question in the above comment. E.g., Unix/Linux usually has `cron` for this. (Answers as below referring to cron using a certain language, usually just point to a wrapper around cron; it's just as easy to learn and use cron directly, if you're on the relevant OS).

Comment: Did you tag the question with `python` because you wrote the script in Python or because you are looking for a Python-based solution?

Comment: Thank you guys! I have done some research on crontab and it is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referring to is often called a "cronjob". Python has a module called `python-crontab` that can do this type of thing. [Here is a tutorial to help you get started](https://stackabuse.com/scheduling-jobs-with-python-crontab/).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about python, but in nodejs, there is a tool called `cronjob`. When you set routine, according to the time that you set, it calls scripts. Maybe there is an equivalent version in python.